# if loop for my google app using handlebar utility

Tags: if-statement, handlebars.js

In this code `isPendingState` returns a true or false value and now I want to check if `empObj.Current_Appraisal_State` is blank or null then I want to print again `Pending`.

```
{{~#if (isPendingState)}}
Pending               
{{~^~}}                 
  {{~empObj.Current_Appraisal_State}}                 
{{~/if~}}
```